# Ubuntu to Ubuntu VNC over SSH tunnel

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, remote-desktop, vnc, tunnel

I have a Linux Ubuntu desktop at home, ssh enabled, vnc server installed, router rule configured. It all works, and at home I can connect via the local network from my Mac. From the outside I can login via ssh.

I've configured putty as follows:

- session: host name and port number
- connection > ssh > tunnel: forwarded ports: L5900|192.168.0.23
- the local address is: 192.168.1.45

When I make the connection I can login to the remote machine.

Then I open Remote Desktop Viewer.

- I click connect
- protocol: vnc
- host: ?
- use host as ssh tunnel: ?

I don't know what to use for the last two options. Which ip-addresses should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSH forwarding - you're forwarding *from the host you have SSHed into*, to the same host:

- L5900|localhost:5900

VNC viewer:

- host: localhost
- "use host as ssh tunnel" is not needed, as you're doing that step (SSH forwarding) manually

Answer (score 0):

You should point your remote desktop viewer to the local address and local port number that you've chosen to bind to.